# JMeter: How to combine responses fetched in each iteration of a loop, in a file without overwriting the existing values?

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter test which sends a GET request to fetch certain data. I am using a while controller and a counter to loop through, till an expected condition is satisfied. Using an Xpath Extractor, I am able to extract the required value from the JMeter response.

However, there is a need to write the data into the same file each time the loop runs, without the data in the file being overwritten. Is there a way to do this? Please find the image attached.

I am newbie to JMeter. Please Help. Thanks.

[JMeter Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bl31.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which "data" and in which format?

1. There is [sample_variables property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) allowing JMeter to store the value of one or more [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) as a separate column
2. You can change the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) label to include the value you want to "write"

   [image]
3. You can use [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) which gives you more or less full control regarding what, where and how to store